# encrypt log file after logrotation

Tags: nginx, cron, pgp, logrotate

I have an nginx logrotation running and my aim is to encrypt the file after being rotated and compressed possibly using pgp, so is there a way to do it as a postrotate or should I use cronjob for that? I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: because I have sensitive data which I need to encrypt and transfer to a backup server. anyway, I already found 2 ways to do it.

Comment: @AbdulT Do you mind posting your solution or reference to your findings? Others might want to do the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a pgp key pair you can do the following in the post-rotate section of your rotation configuration:

```
gpg --output ${1}.$(date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S").gpg --always-trust --encrypt --recipient "your-pgp-username" ${1}.1
```

Details regarding this command:

- The output file is specified to be written according to the timestamp of the rotated file.
- "--always-trust" option is added to avoid manually trusting the public key used.
- "recipient" is the name of the person owning the public key.
- "${1}.1" to encrypt the log file that was just rotated.

Also you shouldn't forget to delete any compressed rotated files and the encrypted files that are older than n day which could be also added in the post-rotate as follows:

```
find /path/to/file/directory -name "*.gz" -mmin +0 -exec rm -f {} \;
find /path/to/file/directory -name "*.gpg" -mtime +n -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Hope this helps!